# Getting Error while fetching data from MongoDb using fastAPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, api, fastapi

This function is to get all the todos from the mongoDB database but when I am trying this is showing error.
When trying find() function from mongo shell then everything is fine but from here it is showing error that coroutine obbject is not iterable and showing type error.
Any help is appreciable!

DB Connection

```
client = motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient('mongodb://localhost:27017')

database = client.TodoList
Collection = database.todo
```

Python Function

```
async def fetch_all_todos():
    todos = []
    cursor = Collection.find({})
    async for document in cursor:
        todos.append(ToDo(**document))
    return todos
```

```
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\protocols\http\h11_impl.py", line 369, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\middleware\proxy_headers.py", line 59, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\fastapi\applications.py", line 199, in __call__      
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\starlette\applications.py", line 112, in __call__    
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 181, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 159, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\starlette\exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__       
    raise exc from None
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\starlette\exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__       
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 580, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 241, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 52, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 224, in app
    response_data = await serialize_response(
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 138, in serialize_response 
    return jsonable_encoder(response_content)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\fastapi\encoders.py", line 141, in jsonable_encoder  
    raise ValueError(errors)
ValueError: [TypeError("'coroutine' object is not iterable"), TypeError('vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to await mongo call

```python
async def fetch_all_todos():
    todos = []
    cursor = await Collection.find({})
    async for document in cursor:
        todos.append(ToDo(**document))
    return todos
```